# Creating a Script to Calculate multiple students and multiple graded assignments that are weighted different amounts

Tags: c++

Creating a Script to Calculate multiple students and multiple graded assignments that are weighted different amounts.

```
 //
 //  main.cpp
 //  PWGHelper
 //
 //  Created by Lyle Baer on 1/18/16.
 //  Copyright © 2016 Lyle Baer. All rights reserved.
 //
 //

 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 using namespace std;

 // Main Script

 int main()
 {
// Vector to store Calculated Grades
vector <int> calculatedGrades;

cout << "Enter Number of Students: \n\n";
int(nStudent);
cin >> nStudent;

// Loop
if (nStudent < 1)
{
    const int MAX = 50;
    float grades[MAX];
    float weights[MAX];

    // Greeting
    cout << "Hello, its me\n\n";
    cout << "Your Personal Weighted Grade Helper\n\n";
    cout << "Call me PWG Helper for short.\n\n";

    // Input # of exercises
    cout << "Enter number of exercises: ";
    int num;
    cin >> num;

    // Input Weights
    int correct = 0;
    while (correct == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            cout << "\nWhat is the weight in percent? ";
            cin >> weights[i];
            weights[i] = weights[i] / (float)100.0;
        }
        correct = 1;
    }
    // Input Grades
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nWhat is the Grade? ";
        cin >> grades[i];
    }

    // Values
    cout << "Printed Values\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << grades[i] << "\n";
        cout << weights[i] << "\n";
    }

    // Find Average
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + grades[i] * weights[i];
    }
    // Total Sum
    cout << "This student has a score of: " << sum;
    cin >> sum;
    calculatedGrades.push_back(sum);

    // Keep console open
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    }
    else
    {
    // Variables
    const int MAX = 50;
    float grades[MAX];
    float weights[MAX];

    // Greeting
    cout << "Hello, its me\n\n";
    cout << "Your Personal Weighted Grade Helper\n\n";
    cout << "Call me PWG Helper for short.\n\n";

    // Input # of exercises
    cout << "Enter number of exercises: ";
    int num;
    cin >> num;

    // Input Weights
    int correct = 0;
    while (correct == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            cout << "\nWhat is the weight in percent? ";
            cin >> weights[i];
            weights[i] = weights[i] / (float)100.0;
        }
        correct = 1;
    }
    // Input Grades
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nWhat is the Grade? ";
        cin >> grades[i];
    }

    // Values
    cout << "Printed Values\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << grades[i] << "\n";
        cout << weights[i] << "\n";
    }

    // Find Average
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + grades[i] * weights[i];
    }
    //Total Sum
    cout << "This student has a score of: " << sum;
    cin >> sum;
    calculatedGrades.push_back(sum);

    // Keep console open
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

**Example output of this code:**

*Enter Number of Students: 3*

*Hello, its me*

*Your Personal Weighted Grade Helper*

*Call me PWG Helper for short.*

*Enter number of exercises: 2*

*What is the weight in percent? 10*

*What is the weight in percent? 10*

*What is the Grade? 85*

*What is the Grade? 97*

*Printed Values*
*85*
*0.1*
*97*
*0.1*
*This student has a score of: 18.2*

Comment: Your while loop doesn't make sense, it will run only once because you are assigning 1 to `correct`.

Comment: @cylon What should I add to have it so it loops each time for multiple students?